# Partitioning a MySQL table based on a column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm working on designing a new database that will need to handle an enormous amount of data. It will be a data warehouse system, and will thus be organized around a central hub table:

```
create table hub(id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
date_time DATETIME NOT NULL, bit_of_data INT NOT NULL);
```

When this table grows very large, it seems that it will be necessary to partition it based on the 'date_time' column, with each partition being, say, one month of data. However, there will also be another table:

```
create table other_data(id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
more_data INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES hub(id));
```

This second table will contain records for about 90% of the ids that appear in the main 'hub' table. I'd like to partition the 'other_data' table as well as the 'hub' table, and have the partitions basically match up with each other. Is there any way to partition the 'hub' table on a date range, and then also partition the 'other_data' table on the same date range?

Thanks!

Comment: Partitioning has to be done based on the contents of the table itself, not the contents of some other table. If you've got a standard number of rows going into the second table per month, you could partition on a range of IDs that roughly matches the insertion rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done only by adding a (redudant) date column in the other_data table.

Comment: There's one possible alteration to this strategy that we may employ in our database. Instead of storing the whole date column in the "other_data" table, we may make the "hub" table keep a composite primary key consisting of a year, month and autoincrement field, which would then be used as the primary key of the other_data table as well. Partitioning could then be done on a month-to-month basis in every table. Instead of a year/month combo, it could also be possible to use just a numerical month column without the year, and have that column increment with each month that passes.